# How do multidimensional-arrays work in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to create a program to train a foreign language.
For that i have two single dimensional array. In the first one i store all the foreign syllables or words and in the second one i'm storing the answers in my native language:

```
$QuestionArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$QuestionArray = "Word1","Word2","Word3"

$AnswerArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$AnswerArray = "Answer1","Answer2","Answer3"
```

Afterwards i check if the entered value is inside the answer-array. If it is i select the index and the index of the randomly selected word from the question-array. If both indexes match then the question has been answered correct otherwise its wrong.

```
$RandomQuestion = $QuestionArray | Get-Random
$Answer = $InputTextbox.Text
$IndexPositionQuestion = [array]::indexof($QuestionArray, $RandomQuestion)
$IndexPositionAnswer = [array]::indexof($AnswerArray, $Answer)

If($IndexPositionAnswer -eq $IndexPositionQuestion){
    $RightTextbox.Text = $script:countercorrect++
}else{
    $WrongTextbox.Text = $script:counterwrong++
}
```

The program works as intended but when i showed it to a colleague today he just told me that the comparing part of the program is coded ugly and is anything but best practice.

How could i go about it in any other way? I read a little bit about multidimensional-arrays but i just can't wrap my head around it. How would i benefit from multidimensional-arrays? How could i select the value i need from it to display, compare, check and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before digging into multidimensional arrays, why dont you try something like an array with hashtables?

```
$array = @(
 @{
  Question = 'blah?'
  Answer = 'blub'
 },
 @{
  Question = 'james'
  Answer = 'Dean'
 } 
)
```

You can reference the values by

```
  for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Count; $i++){
   $array[$i].Question
   $array[$i].Answer
  }
```

in youre example try something like

```
$RandomQuestionNr = 0..($QuestionArray.count -1) | Get-Random
$Answer = $InputTextbox.Text

if($array[$RandomQuestionNr].answer -eq $Answer){
    $RightTextbox.Text = $script:countercorrect++
}else{
    $WrongTextbox.Text = $script:counterwrong++
}
```